# Associate User Control with ViewModel class

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

When I define a `DataTemplate` inline, Visual Studio knows about the type I'm binding to, and properties in that type come up in autocomplete (for example in the code below I was able to select `DisplayName` from the autocomplete list inside the `FirstViewModel` template).

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:FirstViewModel}">
    <StackPanel >
        <Label Content="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:SecondViewModel}">
    <views:SecondView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

However, when the data template references an external control, as for `SecondViewModel` in the code above, when I'm in the file for the `SecondView` usercontrol, since it's just a control, the type isn't bound and the editor doesn't help me with anything.

I've tried wrapping my whole control (inside the `UserControl` element) in the same `DataTemplate` tag, but then my whole view just shows "System.Windows.DataTemplate".

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Gui.Views.Tabs.ExamsTabViews.ExamInfoView"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Gui.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <DataTemplate DataType="vm:ExamInfoViewModel">
        <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

            <!-- contents of the template -->             

        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl>
```

Is there a way to achieve this kind of binding for the editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:SecondViewModel}">
    <views:SecondView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

when this DataTemplate is instantiated, there will be created SecondView and that SecondView will have a SecondViewModel in DataContext. So there is no need any DataTemplate in SecondViewModel control - bind to DataContext instead (`{Binding SecondViewModelProperty}`). To have design-time support for such binding use `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance}`:

```
<UserControl d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:ExamInfoViewModel, 
                             IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}" ...>
```