# Im creating ViewModels from MainViewModel, how can i connect View to my ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

So, i have MainVeiwModel, couple of View and corresponding ViewModels, Im creating Instances of ViewModels in MainViewModel.
What i need is to change Currently displayed View from one of the Views(EditorView).

```
class MainViewModel : UI.Core.ObservableObject
    {
        public UI.Core.RelayCommand SwitchToRuleTab { get; private set; }
        public UI.Core.RelayCommand SwitchToPalletTab { get; private set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            EditorVM = new EditorViewModel(this); 
// i need to either pass commands and some other objects to this VM or refernece to the MainView itself

            SwitchToPalletTab = new Core.RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                //switching to another view
            });
// commands to switch to other views

        }

        public EditorViewModel EditorVM { get; set; }
// other views and stuff

        private object _currentView;

        public object CurrentView
        {
            get { return _currentView; }
            set { 
                _currentView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

In the window xaml file i have set DataContext to MainViewModel and displaying CurrentView using ContentControl. Here is the EditorViewModel code

```
class EditorViewModel
    {
        public MainViewModel VMController { get; private set; }
        public EditorViewModel(MainViewModel Controller)
        {
            VMController = Controller;
        }
    }
```

I also added a DataTemplate with DataType EditorViewModel to the EditorView. But when im trying to reference VMController i can't do it, so i have to set DataContext for the UserControl

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModel:EditorViewModel x:Name="aModel"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Button Command="{Binding aModel.VMController.SwitchToRuleTab}"/>
```

I get the message that EditorViewModel cant be used like that because it dont have a constructor without parameters.
Is there any way to connect the View to the corresponding ViewModel created from the MainViewModel?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61759878/associate-user-control-with-viewmodel-class

Comment: Do not explicitly set the DataContext of a UserControl (or any other control). Declare a control UC that is supposed to visualize a class VM (the view model) in a DataTemplate like `<UC DataType={x:Type VM}">`. Then assign or bind an instance of VM to the Content property of a ContentPresenter, ContentControl or a derived control. The DataTemplate will automatically by applied, i.e. an instanbce of UC will be created and it gets its DataContext automatically assigned to the VM instance.

Comment: See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) for details.